# ¿Cómo importo un módulo que está en una carpeta, desde otro módulo que está en otra carpeta en Python?

Tags: python-3.7

espero estén bien!

Tengo un inconveniente tratando de llamar desde una carpeta en python, a un archivo que está en otra carpeta. Cuando lo intento corro el script, me dice que no existe un módulo con el nombre de mi carpeta. Acá dejo una foto.
[image: Esta es la estructura de mis carpetas]

[image: Y este es el error que me da]

Answer (score 0):

*Python* busca los módulos en las direcciones almacenadas en la variable **path** del módulo *sys*, que es una lista.

Puedes agregar cualquier dirección a esa variable (ya que se trata de una lista):

```
import sys

path = 'C:/...'

sys.path.append(path)

# Aquí ya puedes importar los módulos en - path -
```

Si tienes un script *test.py* en la carpeta *Test*, y un archivo *__init__.py* en la carpeta *Pages*, podrías hacer lo siguiente para que el módulo *Pages* sea accesible desde *test.py*:

```
# ../Test/test.py

import os
import sys

parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)) # ../

sys.path.append(parent_dir)

import Pages
```

En este ejemplo se obtiene la dirección de la carpeta que contiene tanto a *Pages* como a *Test*, y se añade a **sys.path**.

Recuerda que en este ejemplo, para que *Pages* se reconozca como un módulo/paquete debe contener al menos un archivo *__init__.py*.

En cualquier caso, sin necesidad de hacer nada de esto, lo mas sencillo sería mover la carpeta *Pages* al interior de *Test*, ya que por defecto *Python* busca los módulos en el directorio de trabajo del script en ejecución, además de los contenidos en la carpeta *Lib* dentro de la instalación de *Python*.